# Fuzzy Join with Partial String Match in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I came across something new that I've never done before and I'm hoping to get some help. I'm trying to join two data sets (easy enough job), but there are only partial-string matches in two of the columns. I tried to use fuzzy_join, but I can't get it to work for me. Below is what I'm trying to do. I'm hoping to end up with the data frame called df_final. Any ideas?

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~student_id, ~course, ~grade, 
  "001", "social studies grade", "A", 
  "001", "ela grade", "A", 
  "001", "math grade", "A", 
  "002", "social studies grade", "B", 
  "002", "ela grade", "B", 
  "002", "math grade", "B", 
  "003", "social studies grade", "C", 
  "003", "ela grade", "C", 
  "003", "math grade", "C", 
  "004", "social studies grade", "C", 
  "004", "ela grade", "C", 
  "004", "math grade", "C", 
  "005", "social studies grade", "C", 
  "005", "ela grade", "C", 
  "005", "math grade", "C", 
)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~student_id, ~course,
  "001", "5th Social Studies",
  "001", "5th ELA",
  "001", "5th Mathematics",
  "002", "6th Social Studies", 
  "002", "6th ELA",
  "002", "6th Mathematics",
  "003", "8th Social Studies",
  "003", "8th ELA",
  "003", "8th Mathematics",
)

df_final <- tribble(
  ~student_id, ~course, ~grade,
  "001", "5th Social Studies", "A",
  "001", "5th ELA", "A",
  "001", "5th Mathematics", "A",
  "002", "6th Social Studies", "B",
  "002", "6th ELA", "B",
  "002", "6th Mathematics", "B",
  "003", "8th Social Studies", "C",
  "003", "8th ELA", "C",
  "003", "8th Mathematics", "C"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `fuzzyjoin`.  Do a `regex_left_join` after getting the substring from the 'course' columns in both dataset (to make it more matchable)

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 %>% 
   mutate(grp = toupper(str_remove(course, "^\\d+th\\s+"))) %>% 
   regex_left_join(df1 %>%
       mutate(grp = toupper(str_remove(course, 
     "\\s+grade$")), course = NULL), by = c('student_id', "grp")) %>% 
   select(student_id = student_id.x, course, grade)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  student_id course             grade
  <chr>      <chr>              <chr>
1 001        5th Social Studies A    
2 001        5th ELA            A    
3 001        5th Mathematics    A    
4 002        6th Social Studies B    
5 002        6th ELA            B    
6 002        6th Mathematics    B    
7 003        8th Social Studies C    
8 003        8th ELA            C    
9 003        8th Mathematics    C
```

OP's expected output is

```
 df_final
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  student_id course             grade
  <chr>      <chr>              <chr>
1 001        5th Social Studies A    
2 001        5th ELA            A    
3 001        5th Mathematics    A    
4 002        6th Social Studies B    
5 002        6th ELA            B    
6 002        6th Mathematics    B    
7 003        8th Social Studies C    
8 003        8th ELA            C    
9 003        8th Mathematics    C
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in this example. I think it's something with fuzzyjoin, but not sure exactly. how to use it.

Comment: The updated one works! I guess in this example it was pretty straightforward to use regex to pull out similar words and make two new columns.

Comment: @Mishalb thank you.  I was thinking that regex_left_join should have worked on the original data, but some additioanl string prevented it from matching correctly

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest exploring possibility of using commonly accepted ways of comparing string distances, in my view this constitutes the *actual* fuzzy approach to matching. Regex-based matching is simply deterministic matching (equally, you could transform your columns first and then do the left join). The solution below uses `comparator` package to derive matching function returning Jaro-Winkler string distance and undertakes "fuzzy" matching. In your particular example regex may be more appropriate, but in NLP the actual "fuzziness" is usually defined in the context of string distances or a more sophisticated NLP-processing, thing of a situation where you may wish to account for common spelling mistakes, etc. Encapsulating that in a regex will prove onerous.

```
jw <- comparator::JaroWinkler()

fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
    x = df1, y = df2, by = "course",
    match_fun = function(x, y) { jw(x, y) > 0.1}
)
```

## Example

Your regex will fail miserably if the world `grade` is mistyped as `grade` but `JaroWinkler` string distance will show strong proximity:

```
>> jw("grade", "grde")
[1] 0.9466667
```

That's robust if you are dealing with diverse data set where you can't rely on a column having a well-defined pattern.

Comment: Is there a difference in how the string matching algorithms are implemented between `fuzzyjoin` (using `stringdist`) and `comparator`? Will this give the same result as using `fuzzyjoin::stringdist_left_join` with `method = "jw"`?